# select вместо input

Tags: javascript, html

Как этот код

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  const query = [...checkboxes]
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.name)
    .join('+')
  const url = 'https://example.ru/search/' + query;

  // not working in sandbox
  // window.location.href = url;
  alert('redirect to ' + url);
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Москва"><label>Москва</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Лондон" value="Лондон"><label>Лондон</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Париж" value="Париж"><label>Париж</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Вашингтон" value="Вашингтон">
  <label>Вашингтон</label>
  <button>Подобрать</button>
</form>
```

Переделать на select option
Естественно вопрос относится к JS

Answer (score 1):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = form.country.querySelectorAll('option');
  const url = 'https://example.ru/search/';
  for (var n = 0; n < options.length; n++) {
    if (options[n].selected == true)
      alert('redirect to ' + url + options[n].value);
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="country">
    <option value="Москва">Москва</option>
    <option value="Лондон">Лондон</option>
    <option value="Париж">Париж</option>
    <option value="Вашингтон">Вашингтон</option>
  </select>
  <button>Подобрать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: А если у меня 2 select ?

Comment: конкретнее укажите, что вы хотите получить от 2 select

Comment: Есть страна и город. есть связные селекты, человек выбрал страну и выбрал город после нажал на кнопку  урл стал страна+город. Если он выбрал только страну то в url только страна